# Is it a good idea to use Singleton pattern for an API manager?

Tags: design-patterns, ios, objective-c

So basically I am writing a wrapper for a REST API in objective-c so that our customer can easily use them in their iOS development.

I am trying to find a good design pattern for this purpose, it seems Singleton Design Pattern is the only choice here. Without a public initializer, it is a shared manager accessible by calling a function and thus every controller in their app can access it.

I am seeking some advice for such a purpose: to design a wrapper for API. Should I use the Singleton design pattern? Or I should allow them to inherit this class and create it on their own risk?

Comment: You've failed to explain the requirement here. This should only ever be constructed once.... why?

Comment: you may refer to this on why we should avoid singeltons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: But note that arguments against singletons are very often based on assumptions about implementation which don't apply to Objective-C. There are only two real arguments against singletons in Objective-C: If they create a bottleneck (possible on an immensely powerful server) - or if you need more than one.

Comment: BTW. It is customary in Objective-C to not waste your time on trying to prevent developers from creating a second instance beyond forbidding to use the "init" method outside the implementation of the Singleton class. If they want to shoot themselves in the foot that's not your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the advice is not to use the singleton pattern to implement global variables.

However, here your objective seems to be 'Implement a global variable' as this will 'make it easy' for your customer.

You could well be right, global variables do make it easy to get up and running with something. If your customer needs help writing a client for your api maybe that is exactly the kind of help they want and need.

However, I would do both, allow the client to be instantiated if required **AND** provide a singleton wrapper class for newbies.

This will cover you for other more advanced customers who want to do things the singleton prevents, whilst also giving you the easy 'just make it work' minimal code tutorial for your 'my first app' customers

Comment: You Ain't Going to Need It.

Comment: And I couldn't find anything about accessing "global variables" in the question.

Comment: A singleton is effectively a global variable - the static instance variable is accessible globally via the static instance function.

Comment: Bdsl - that’s nonsense. A global variable is accessible _without_ any function. And “static instance function “ is a contradiction in itself. There’s no such thing.

Comment: @gnasher729 how do you interpret " it is a shared manager and every controller in their app can access it."

Comment: @bdsl another (the correct?) way to use singletons is to hide the singleton so its an internal implementation detail of a class. eg connection pooling by connection objects.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it is accessible through a function. I just update the answer.

Comment: @Ewan: There is some means to access it. Global variable would be utterly stupid, because any code could replace it. Typical way to access it is using a class method (static method in C++) which creates the singleton when it's first used and from then on returns the same singleton to anyone using it.

Comment: @gnasher729 yeah, when you do that its a global variable singleton.

Comment: Really, the correct answer is "Use dependency injection" followed by "Learn dependency injection." However I've worked in code bases that use the singleton pattern for this sort of thing. It is quick to get up and running. When you start encountering the problems you get with singletons, then the other part of your answer is spot on. Give them both.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think bdsl meant "The static function (conventionally named) `instance()`"

Answer (score 2):

I recommend against this approach. I suggest that instead of doing that, you make an extension on URLRequest that contains a class method for each kind of request that can be made to your API. These methods should return a properly built URLRequest.

When the user of the library wants to make a request, (s)he can simply construct the URLRequest and pass it to URLSession, AFNetworking or any other networking library they choose to use/create.

It's much more flexible, composable and testable.